# SQLite . Add the values in two columns and output in another column without showing the two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with information like this.

```
ID      | Name    | #ofCow  | UItem   | place
--------+---------+-------- +---------+----------
0       | Bob      | 7       | 1      | maine
1       | Bob      | 3       | 5      | new york
2       | Tom      | 2       | 5      | cali
```

I wish to produce a table like this where it would add up the number of cows and Uitem if the name is the same. However my select query seems to not be working. I suspect it is because the place column is the problem. Since you can't add 'Maine' and 'New York' together. Can anyone help me find a solution ?

```
ID      | Name    | #ofCow  | UItem   | 
--------+---------+-------- +---------+
0       | Bob      | 10       | 6     | 
2       | Tom      | 2       | 5      |
```

TLDR : Add the values in two columns in table 1 if name is same. Output in another column. Don't show the two columns. I don't need places also.

Comment: This should be a simple SUM() + GROUP BY query. What did you try? Show the SQL please.

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework ... please let us know if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this (I have considered the name of the table as HolyCow) :

```
SELECT     holy.ID,
           holy.Name, 
           SUM(holy.Cows) as '#ofCow',
           SUM(holy.UItem) as 'UItem'
FROM       HolyCow holy
GROUP BY   holy.ID, holy.Name
ORDER BY   holy.Name
```

Hope this helps!!